# Adding Telerik RadAjaxManagerProxy causes RadEditor in RadGrid to Fail

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have a RadGrid using GridTemplateColumn and have implemented a RadEditor to provide a rich text edit control.  This worked until I added the RadAjaxManagerProxy to the top of the page.  When I add a new record, or edit an existing one, the RadEditors don't work.  The other columns work fine.

**THE PROXY LOOKS LIKE:**
Nothing special here...

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy runat="server" ID="ajaxProxy">
        <AjaxSettings>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="pnlMain">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="pnlMain" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        </AjaxSettings>
    </telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy>
```

The RadGrid is inside pnlMain along with other controls that need to be AJAXified.

**THIS IS WHAT I HAVE TRIED:**

- Adding an AjaxSetting specifically for the RadGrid (No effect)
- Moving the RadAjaxManagerProxy to the bottom of the page
- Removing the RadAjaxManagerProxy solves the problem, but also removes the ability for the page to be AJAXified.

Let me know if you need more code samples.

Answer (score 0):

Coul'd You provide the RadGrid code?

Have you added [EnableAjax](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/grid/radgrid-telerik.webcontrols.radgrid-enableajax.html)="true" to the RadGrid

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion and it didn't work either.  We have decided to go without AJAX for now.